# How do I complete an existing attribute table with .CSV or .XLSX

Tags: qgis, csv, excel, table

I have an existing vector layer (points) I was working on some time ago. The layer represents boreholes in the area of my interest (over 250 points).

Some time ago we got access to a number of geological documentations and my colleague updated some of the information regarding the boreholes in the Excel file. He used the same headers that I used in QGIS.

Is it possible in QGIS after adding a CSV or XLSX file for the join to fill in the missing gaps in an existing column rather than adding a completely new column?

For example, in the screenshot, you see a column named "do_str_wwy" - it represents the depth to the aquifer.

[image]

In the XLSX file, I have an identical column with completed values for the selected boreholes. What I want to accomplish is to fill in the NULL values in the existing column, because right now QGIS creates a whole new column every time and I don't know how it will handle this.

[image]

Comment: Do the join, use the field calculator to complete the pre-join fields with the joined field (`if("field_x1" is NULL, "field_x2","field_x1")`), then remove the join.

Answer (score 4):

Using the examples you've shown, if you are using the `Odwiert_na` column as the key column to perform the join, you can use field calculator in your vector layer to overwrite the `do_str_wwy` column in one stroke with the following expression (replace new_layer_name accordingly). Note the use of single and double quotes

```
 attribute(get_feature('new_layer_name','Odwiert_na',"Odwiert_na"),'do_str_wwy')
```

This is essentially a lookup/join expression. This overwrites the entire column.

The structure works like this:

`attribute(get_feature('other_layer_name','other_layer_matching_key_column',"current_layer_key_column"),'other_layer_desired_attribute')`

`get_feature()` goes through your current layer's key column and grabs a matching feature (row) from the other layer based on matching values in the other layer's specified column.

`attribute()` then extracts the specific attribute from that matching feature.

---

Or if you want to keep the existing values in `do_str_wwy` in your vector layer, and only fill in values if the field is NULL,

`coalesce("do_str_wwy",
attribute(get_feature('new_layer_name','Odwiert_na',"Odwiert_na"),'do_str_wwy'))`

`coalesce()` returns the first non-null value so if `do_str_wwy` has a value, it uses that, otherwise it applies the lookup expression.